# How to use a link to a location on a page which seems to include spaces?

Tags: support

In [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19939/12102) I want to link to the "Loading Auxiliary Files" subsection of [this JPL document](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/C/req/spk.html). If I click it there - within the table of contents, it jumps to the correct location. However, the link in the table of contents contains the actual spaces between the three words.

https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/C/req/spk.html#Loading Auxiliary Files

...and as you can see, stackexchange is ignoring everything after the first space, as does my browser if I paste it there. Adding underscores, truncating after the first word, deleting the spaces all fail as they should.

Is this an unlinkable link, or an unpostable link? Or is there a helpful work-around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put "%20" in between instead of spaces, like this:

https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/C/req/spk.html#Loading%20Auxiliary%20Files

"%20" is the URL code for space.

Comment: Very nice! I've updated the question - it works perfectly. Thanks!